# How can I check if a command-line argument is equal to '<' from input in Perl?

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

foreach $arg (@ARGV) {
        if ($arg eq "--version") {
                print "$0: version 0.1\n";
                exit(0);
        } elsif ($arg =~ /-[0-9]+/) {
                $n = $arg;
                $n =~ s/-//g;
        } elsif ($arg eq <){
                print "in";
        } else {
                push @files, $arg;
        }
}
```

How can I check if $arg is equal to < from input?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You correctly used quotes for the string `--version`. You should use quotes for `<`, too.

Note that you are checking command line arguments, not input. Also note that on *nix systems, if you call the script like

```
myscript.pl -12 < input
```

the `< input` part is processed by the shell and doesn't appear in the argument list.

See also [Getopt::Long](http://p3rl.org/Getopt::Long).

Comment: @hahahakebab: Why do you need it? You can read the contents of the redirected file from standard input.

Comment: @hahahakebab, There's no way to differentiate `bash -c 'myscript.pl 12 <input'` (`<` used in command) from `bash -c 'myscript.pl 12' <input` (`<` not used in command). For starters, you can't even tell if the program was launched from a shell command or not.

Answer (score 0):

@hahahakebab: What @choroba said is exactly correct. When you are passing < as the command line argument put that in double quote "<" so that it takes as input to the program and modified code as below

```
    foreach my $arg (@ARGV) {
            if ($arg eq "--version") {
                    print "$0: version 0.1\n";
                    exit(0);
            } elsif ($arg =~ /-[0-9]+/) {
                    $n = $arg;
                    $n =~ s/-//g;
            } elsif ($arg eq "<"){
                    print "in";
            } else {
                    push @files, $arg;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `<` was used in the command line, then standard input is coming from a file.
If `<` was not used in the command line (and `|` is not used to specify input from the output stream of another process), then standard input is from a terminal.

You can distinguish between these two cases in Perl by checking [`-t STDIN`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#X)

```
if (-t STDIN) {
    print "input is from terminal\n";
} else {
    print "input is from a file/pipe\n";
}
```